# XML element with attribute has ":" in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a problem when I am getting the attributes of a xml file. These attributes are written like this:

`@XmlAttribute(name="xml:lang")`

With @XmlAttribute I get attributes that they are written on a one word. If I leave this annotation `@XmlAttribute(name="xml:lang")` I get null

How can I get attribute's value of "xml:lang"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xml` is clearly a [**namespace prefix**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html#namespace()). You can try stating the namespace it with:

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "lang", 
              namespace = javax.xml.XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI)
```